# currency symbol not showing in pdf invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

[image: pdf invoice]

the first digit is cancelled and the currency symbol isn't showing. how can i resolve this issues

Comment: What is the symbol?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Symbol is part of the font you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Please following below steps to solve the issue:-

1. Choose a font that supports your currency symbol.
2. Copy that supported font file (*fontname.ttf*) to `magento_root/lib/<project_name>/` directory.
3. Copy both files `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php` and `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php`
   to
   `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php` and `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php` respectively.
4. Open both newly created files and replace
   `$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_Re-4.4.1.ttf');`
   by
   `$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/<project_name>/fontname.ttf');`

Hope, if someone follow all these steps the problem should be solved.